# Remove Title suffix from Product Page only

Tags: magento-1.8, product, page-title

How do i remove title suffix only from product page. My current Page title is like [Product Name] - [Website Address] here i want to remove website address only from product page which means it should appear in all rest of the pages. Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom module and hook the event `catalog_controller_product_view`

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                        <method>changeProductTitle</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

And in your `Observer.php` define the function like below

```
public function changeProductTitle($observer) {

        if ($product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()) {
            $title = $product->getData('name');
            $product->setMetaTitle($title);
            $product->setTitle($title);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Modify the code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go into pages under `cms` in `magento` back-end and check out if there is a product page, click edit and see what the title of the certain page is.

Or check the following link it may be helpful

http://inchoo.net/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/

Comment: Sorry I don't have any product page under cms, Is there any other way to do this?. Thanks

Comment: i edited my answer give it a go